# Passing arguments to ViewModels manually

Tags: android, dependency-injection

i have the following viewmodel

```
class SharedViewModel (
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    val database: FirebaseFirestore?, 
    val auth : FirebaseAuth?) : ViewModel()
{
// viewmodel stuff
}
```

how do i pass arguments to it when i create it in the main activity? i read a bit about factories here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories
but it's still unclear to me how i pass the database and auth arguments (the docs only have code on passing shared state handle). I'm using Kotlin and Compose exclusevily by the way.

**Why not use Hilt or Koin?**
I've heard there's considerable overhead to these libraries which doesn't seem necessary when i'd only need them in this instance alone. (entire project is Hilt-free).

Answer (score 0):

Make Factory like below in your SharedViewModel class

```
  class SharedViewModel(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val database: FirebaseFirestore?,
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth?
 ) : ViewModel() {
 
    class Factory(
        private val application: Application,
        private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
        private val database: FirebaseFirestore?,
        private val auth: FirebaseAuth?
    ) : ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application) {


        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(SharedViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return SharedViewModel(savedStateHandle, database, auth) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
        }
    }
}
```

and try to initialize and call viewModel in your MainActivity like this:

```
  val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by viewModels {
        SharedViewModel.Factory(
            application,
            savedStateHandle,
            firebaseFirestoreInstance,
            firebaseAuthInstance
        )
    }
```

I hope it work :)